# ExecuteScalar returns false for SQL count(*)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following function to check if a user exists in my SQL table

```
private static bool  userexists(string user)
{
    bool userexists = false;

    SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from UserTable where Username = @user");
    c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user",user));
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString))
    {
        userexists = (bool)c.ExecuteScalar();
        return userexists;
    }
}
```

it returns `false` even if the user exists, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you executed the same statement in the database? what does it returns. I have my reservations over this approach as well. You should check for userid rather than username. Multiple users can have same username whereas userid will be unique.

Comment: Also: it would be much better performance-wise to use a `IF EXISTS()....`  approach in SQL. Imagine you have 100 million users in your table; to check the existence of a given user, based on your approach, **100 million** rows will have to be scanned to count how many times that user occurs. The `IF EXISTS()` approach can stop scanning as soon as it finds a matching user ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting back a number, you should cast it so and add a condition to get a `bool` result

```
userexists = (int) c.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

change this line :

```
        userexists = (bool)c.ExecuteScalar();
```

to this :

```
        userexists = (int32)c.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE WHEN Count(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as UserExists from.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your problem by

```
        userexists = (int)c.ExecuteScalar() > 0.
```

But, I have my reservations over this approach as well. You should check for userid rather than username. Multiple users can have same username whereas userid will be unique.

Comment: The input probably is the username so there is no reason for changing this query. The function check if the user exists, so it does the job even if there is more than one match (although I doubt usernames aren't uniques)